# Saving the vectors generated by the recursion loop (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have the following matlab code which does a variable nested loop:

```
function rec_function(numLoops, loopVars, index, NINT)
if numLoops == 0
    loopVars
    return
end

for k = 1:NINT(1,index)
    loopVars(1,index) = (k-1)/(NINT(1,index)-1);
    rec_function(numLoops-1, loopVars, index+1, NINT);
end
end
```

where the highlighted part will do something like this:

```
>> rec_function(2,zeros(1,2),1, [2 2])

loopVars =

     0     0


loopVars =

     0     1


loopVars =

     1     0


loopVars =

     1     1
```

I would like to ask how can i save the vector loopVars of each loop in a matrix for further use, e.g.:

```
A = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]
```

Comment: like this? `A=[A;loopVars]`

Comment: yes i did that in the if part but it says that the variable A is being used before it was defined.

Comment: `>> rec_function(2,zeros(1,2),1, [2 2])
Undefined function or variable "A".

Error in rec_function (line 3)
        A=[A;loopVars];

Error in rec_function (line 9)
        rec_function(numLoops-1, loopVars, index+1, NINT);

Error in rec_function (line 9)
        rec_function(numLoops-1, loopVars, index+1, NINT);`

Comment: so just add `A=[] at the beginning (it is not very nice, since A is growing in the loop, but... it should do the trick)

Comment: define it first, something like A = zeros(NINT(1,index),2);

Comment: i did that too if I add A=[] right before A=[A;loopVars] it will do the same, furthermore the matrix won't be added to the workspace because it's a local variable for the function, but let me thank you guys first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to use [global variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html#f0-38470):

```
function rec_function(numLoops, loopVars, index, NINT)
global loopVars_all;
if numLoops == 0
    loopVars_all(end + 1, :) = loopVars;
    return
end

for k = 1:NINT(1,index)
    loopVars(1,index) = (k-1)/(NINT(1,index)-1);
    rec_function(numLoops-1, loopVars, index+1, NINT);
end
end
```

You call it like this:

```
global loopVars_all;
loopVars_all = [];
rec_function(2, zeros(1,2), 1, [2 2]);
loopVars_all

loopVars_all =

     0     0
     0     1
     1     0
     1     1
```